# Array of arrays -- JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project which I am asked to make a database for a company that has 3 different types of employees, `Programmer/Student` `Programmer/QATester`, I have make for each one of those an array of it's type, because each one has it's own specific notes, The problem is,I am asked that if someone would search an employee through ID number and gets his name, I need to search through all of them, so I though about making an Array of Arrays, which has those 3 arrays.
But here is what happens:

```
public class EmployeesDB {
private String companyName;
private int programmers;
private int studentProgrammers;
private int QATesters;
public Programmer[] ProgrammersArray;
public StudentProgrammer[] StudentsArray;
public QATester[] QATArray;
public String[][] KO ;

public EmployeesDB(String name, int numOfProgrammers, int numOfStudents, int numOfTesters) {
    this.companyName = name;
    this.programmers = numOfProgrammers;
    this.studentProgrammers = numOfStudents;
    this.QATesters = numOfTesters;

    StudentsArray = new StudentProgrammer[numOfStudents];
    ProgrammersArray = new Programmer[numOfProgrammers];
    QATArray = new QATester[numOfTesters];
    KO = new String[][]{StudentsArray,ProgrammersArray,QATArray};
}
```

and it keeps showing :

```
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from StudentProgrammer[] to String[]
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Programmer[] to String[]
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from QATester[] to String[]
```

I am new, and I am not able to find a solution.

Please help me. 
thank you!

Comment: Can you explain in English what you are trying to do?  As the error message suggests, the code doesn't make sense as a `StudentProgrammer` is not a `String`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert 3 Arrays of different Classes to String Arrays

```
KO = new String[][]{StudentsArray,ProgrammersArray,QATArray};
```

You will have to do that into a Object[][], and then use instance of whenever you need

```
public Object[][] KO ;
//...
KO = new Object[][]{StudentsArray,ProgrammersArray,QATArray};
if (KO[0][0] instanceof Programmer) {...}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, the Polymorphic nature of Java Objects can be exploited for our advantage.
NOTE: any 1 of these 2 soltion cases can be utilised to get the desired results.

---

1. Assuming you *DON'T WANT* the classes `Programmer`, `StudentProgrammer` and `QATester` to be subclasses of String, you can proceed as:

Instead of declaring KO as:

```
public String[][] KO ;
```

you can declare KO as:

```
public Employee[][] KO;
```

where `Employee` is the super class of classes `Programmer`, `StudentProgrammer` and `QATester`.

2. Assuming you *WANT* the classes `Programmer`, `StudentProgrammer` and `QATester` to be subclasses of String, you can simply make these 3 classes extend the class `String`.

---

Now, to access an element of the array `KO`, and to convert it back to its abstract form, you can simply proceed as:

```
if(KO[x][y] instanceof Programmer){
    Programmer employeeAtXandY = (Programmer) KO[x][y];
    System.out.println("Employee Element at x and y is a Programmer");
}
```